# Choosing A Value based on given value in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**Problem**

Lets say that I have the following two rows,

A B C D E F G H I J K L M

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4

On the other hand, there is the following column:
A

B

C

D

I want excel to recognize the letters in the column and provide the result from the corresponding row. so that whenever I write A in the column, then excel should give out the output 1 in the right column. Likewise same for B and C. I can not use a transpose, because I have to change the letters on regular basis.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the lesser known lookup function for this `HLOOKUP`.

In my example below I used the formula:

```
=HLOOKUP(A6,1:2,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

You could also use `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

```
=INDEX(A2:E2,1,MATCH(A6,A1:E1,0))
```

Another alternative would be to use `OFFSET` and `MATCH`, this is the most dynamic lookup formula I use, but it is also costly as it is volatile.

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,MATCH(A6,1:1,0)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks a Bunch! It works like a charm!